# Printing a string with newline as text ("example \n example" in one line)

Tags: swift

Im working on balancing some text over multiple lines and I am adding manual newLines to split the text evenly over the lines. To figure it out i need to see where the "\n" are added for testing my code, but the only way ive found is to print it all out as character:

```
["T", "i", "r", "s", "d", "a", "g", " ", "f", "i", "k", "k", " ", "1", "5", " ", "b", "a", "r", "n", " ", "i", " ", "G", "r", "a", "n", "s", "t", "u", "b", "b", "e", "n", " ", "b", "a", "r", "n", "e", "h", "a", "g", "e", " ", "h", "a", "g", "e", "t", " ", "s", "e", "g", " ", "b", "a", "m", " ", "b", "a", "m", " ", "s", "h", "a", "r", "k", " ", "w", "e", "e", "k", " ", "f", "o", "r", " ", "l", "i", "f", "e", " ", "a", "n", "d", " ", "f", "o", "r", " ", "e", "v", "e", "r"]
```

Its a pain to find new \n symbols in here and I am now wondering if i could see it as a string in any way. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am unable to uderstand the question.

Comment: @UmairAfzal I dont want to scroll through that long array of chars to find the "\n". But if i print it as a regular string, the "\n" does not show in the text, it is starts printing on a new line. But i dont want to print on a new line. I want to see the "\n" in the string.

Comment: you want to print this on console as it s "something \n something"

Comment: @UmairAfzal Sure. I want:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the string by newline and join it with any visible character  you like (in the example with `~~~`)

```
myString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).joined(separator: "~~~")
```

Comment: Not that you needn't include `CharacterSet` here (`.newlines` suffices): the  type for the `separatedBy` argument is known from the signature of the `components(separatedBy:)` method. This allows us to access static members of the type without prefixing the type itself (in this case, the static member `.newlines`, which is, itself, of type `CharacterSet`).

Answer (score 0):

Because '\' is an escaped charecter so you can print it like this

```
print("something \\n something")
```